# Can't find socket.io for client when server is created without handler

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Browser can't find socket.io.js for client:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

When server is created without handler:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs');

app.listen(80);

//without this part:
/*function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}*/

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

I don't need and don't want handler function because everything I generate in PHP. And sometimes use client application functions for another file than index.html/php

So how to make browser can find socket.io.js?

Comment: Don't you need a static handler of some kind to serve up the socket.io.js file when it is requested? No routing happens by default with node.js.

Comment: Ok but even with handler function browser can't find socket.io.js. And this code above is example of using socket.io...

Comment: Your handler function serves the index page, but does not serve the socket.io.js file. As I already said, node.js will _not_ serve up _any_ files by default, unless you explicitly tell it to do so, or install a module which does.

Comment: finally I can imagine how it work. Thanks, will try it.

Comment: But if i want to serve socket.io.js what directory i have to set here: fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've [wrote](https://github.com/dotcloud/socket.io-on-dotcloud) a demo app that you could have a look at if you don't want to loose to much time getting started with socket.io and Express 3.

To have websockets working your client js needs to be delivered from a webserver. This is one of those many browser limitation.
The easiest setup is to have a node server that provide both the client side Js and the WebSockets. Using easier the http module of Express (a bit overkill but super practical if you want to build something more than just a test app).

Other wise you need to have your client side js pointing to the right place. For example if you run your socket.io server of port 8080 and you deliver your static client side on port 8000 (using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` for example or port 80 using a regular apache).

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: how do you deliver you Js ? Do you use the `file://` protocol ? because this will never works. It needs to me a deliver through a webserver. Socket.io is a just a WebSocket handler not a http content delivering framework. This is why it is often coupled with Express.

Comment: I normally run server script on my server. And normally run my site by address where i use http protocol in code.

Comment: I highly recommend that you have a look at the doc or the demo app that I just provided you. You seems quite confused on what socket.io is. Once again when you point to `/socket.io/socket.io.js` and run the Js from another server or worse no server just the file:// protocol what do you think can happen ?. There is no magie.

Comment: everything is on same server.

Comment: I used your code, but some things removed. http://pastebin.com/HerGHp78 and still browser cant find socket.io.js, but server starts correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need access to http module functionality use this way:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: The problem is that the client doesn't get the js. The socket code is irrelevant.

Comment: `/socket.io/socket.io.js` delivered by socket.io module. This code work fine for me on node.js 0.8.7 and socket.io 0.9.9

Answer (score 0):

Include this on your client side !

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> 
var io = io.connect();
```

Comment: The whole point of OP's post was to figure out why your exact solution is NOT working because the socket.io server is not serving the js under `/socket.io/socket.io.js` as expected. So your answer does not provide any value here as the problem is on the server side.